# Escaping HTML special characters in Solidity

Tags: solidity, string, bytes

I realize I am not supposed to do this, and yet I am curious about the least-bad approach.

Will the code below work? It is based on [some of Uniswap's code](https://github.com/Uniswap/v3-periphery/blob/main/contracts/libraries/NFTDescriptor.sol#L85).

```
function escapeHTML(string memory input)
    public
    pure
    returns (string memory)
{
    bytes memory inputBytes = bytes(input);
    uint extraCharsNeeded = 0;
    
    for (uint i = 0; i < inputBytes.length; i++) {
        bytes1 currentByte = inputBytes[i];
        
        if (currentByte == "&") {
            extraCharsNeeded += 4;
        } else if (currentByte == "<") {
            extraCharsNeeded += 3;
        } else if (currentByte == ">") {
            extraCharsNeeded += 3;
        }
    }
    
    if (extraCharsNeeded > 0) {
        bytes memory escapedBytes = new bytes(
            inputBytes.length + extraCharsNeeded
        );
        
        uint256 index;
        
        for (uint i = 0; i < inputBytes.length; i++) {
            if (inputBytes[i] == "&") {
                escapedBytes[index++] = "&";
                escapedBytes[index++] = "a";
                escapedBytes[index++] = "m";
                escapedBytes[index++] = "p";
                escapedBytes[index++] = ";";
            } else if (inputBytes[i] == "<") {
                escapedBytes[index++] = "&";
                escapedBytes[index++] = "l";
                escapedBytes[index++] = "t";
                escapedBytes[index++] = ";";
            } else if (inputBytes[i] == ">") {
                escapedBytes[index++] = "&";
                escapedBytes[index++] = "g";
                escapedBytes[index++] = "t";
                escapedBytes[index++] = ";";
            } else {
                escapedBytes[index++] = inputBytes[i];
            }
        }
        return string(escapedBytes);
    }
    
    return input;
}
```

Comment: Why do you want string processing in solidity? I would avoid any processing that can be done off-chain. Even if they are in view functions it takes a lot of space in the bytecode.

Comment: @Ismael I am working on an NFT project where users can enter text when they mint the NFT and then that text is added to a dynamically-generated SVG that serves as the image data in the Token URI. The spirit of the idea is to put everything on the blockchain, so I am assembling the SVG on-demand in the contract and I need to put user input into it without breaking things. I realize this is not recommended but maybe it could be fun? Haha.

Comment: Sorry for not adding it as a comment, I can't do that since I do not have enough reputation. I am trying to achieve what you described in your comment. Did you actually find a solution for that? Or, does this code work? :D